# Obtener una función en más de dos celdas en Excel

Tags: excel, vba, formulas, fórmulas-de-matriz

Tengo programada una función de *Excel* (la cual adjunto) que tiene dos resultados, y requiero que los dos resultados, salgan en una celda contigua cada uno.

[image: Excel de presentación]

```
Function T_1muestra(selection, V_referencia, significancia, nro_colas)
Dim Tobs, Tcrit_2C, Tcrit_1C, Tc As Double
Dim n As Integer
Dim conclusión As String

n = WorksheetFunction.Count(selection)

Tobs = Abs(
   WorksheetFunction.Average(selection)-V_referencia
) * Sqr(n) / WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(selection)
Tcrit_2C = WorksheetFunction.T_Inv_2T(significancia, n - 1)
Tcrit_1C = Abs(WorksheetFunction.T_Inv_2T(significancia * 2, n - 1))
If nro_colas = 1 Then
   Tc = Tcrit_1C
Else
   Tc = Tcrit_2C
End If

If Tobs <= Tc Then
   conclusion =
      "Como To <= Tc --> Se concluye que el experimento cumple el Test de 1 muestra"
Else
   conclusion =
      "Como To > Tc --> Se concluye que el experimiento NO cumple el Test de 1 muestra"

T_1muestra = "H0: Promedio = " & V_referencia & " H1_Promefio <> " & V_referencia & _
   " Significancia de la prueba: " & significancia &
   " Prueba realizada a " & nro_colas & " colas" & _
   " Tobservado = " & Tobs & ". Tcritico " & Tc & " " & conclusion

End Function
```

Comment: Hola @ManuelBlanco. Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Podrías publicar tu código como texto? Una imagen no siempre se visualiza bien, sobre todo en dispositivos con pantallas chicas, o se le complica a personas con problemas de vista. Además, sería más sencillo para que alguien que intente responder pueda copiar tu código... Todo eso, sin mencionar que la tipografía que estás usando me resulta bastante tediosa.

Comment: Además, convendría que expliques cuáles son los valores que estás interesado en mostrar... Y, ¿no te conviene hacer 2 funciones diferentes? Una que devuelva el valor que vas a mostrar en la primera celda, y otra función para la segunda?

Comment: A mí si me parece que está claro. Se trata de una función personalizada al cual cual devuelve como resultado una matriz. Una de las situaciones que está enfrentando el OP es que Excel no depliega en automático las matrices al área/rango que requiere.

Answer (score 1):

En Excel las matrices no se expanden automáticamente, contrario a lo que ocurre en otras aplicaciones como las Hojas de Cálculo de Google.

El procedimiento a seguir es el suguiente:

1. Conocer el tamaño de la matriz. En este caso, es sencillo porque el tamaño es fijo, y es de 9 renglones y 1 columna.
2. Seleccionar el rango en el que se desea que la matriz sea desplegada, cuidando que la celda de la esquina superior izquierda se mantenga como la celda activa.
3. Escribir `=`, seguido de la fórmula y presionar <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Mayúsculas</kbd> + <kbd>Entrar</kbd>. En este caso, la fórmula es el nombre de la función personaliza con los parámetros correspondientes.

Se deberá mostrar la matriz.

Cabe mencionar que las funciones personalizadas no pueden alterar las propiedades de las celdas, pero lo que existe la opción de usar una macro / sub procedure para automatizar la introducción de una fórmula de matriz, para ello usar la propiedad [Range.formulaArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/office/ff837104.aspx)

Referencia

[Instrucciones y ejemplos de fórmulas de matriz en Excel 2016 para Windows](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Instrucciones-y-ejemplos-de-f%C3%B3rmulas-de-matriz-en-Excel-2016-para-Windows-bc6b94c5-f1e2-40fd-8513-cc8c452d4d89)

Answer (score 0):

Encontré [ésta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12504471/1732224) en SO (en inglés) e hice unas adaptaciones para explicarlo aquí.

Básicamente se utilizan dos funciones:

1. La función de usuario principal y que será ingresada como fórmula en una celda de Excel (agregada a un módulo nuevo en VBA).
2. El procedimiento para el evento `Worksheet_Calculate()`, agregado al código de la hoja de trabajo (`Hoja1` o `Sheet1` y no `ThisWorkbook`).

A continuación pongo el ejemplo que preparé de ambas funciones.

---

#### Código de Módulo1

Éste código básicamente ejecuta la función objeto del problema y guarda información en variables globales (`Public`) que serán usadas como base para dibujar el resultado en las celdas anexas. La parte importante es la referencia de la celda de origen (donde se ingresó la fórmula) y un arreglo con los elementos adjuntos al resultado (resumen, conclusiones, información extra, etc.); además, habilitamos una bandera que permite señalizar que se deberá dibujar dicho resultado.

```vb
Public disparar_F1 As Boolean      ' valor que determina si se dibuja o no el resultado para esta fórmula
Public resultado_F1(2) As Variant  ' arreglo que contiene los valores resultantes (3 líneas para este ejercicio)
Public origen_F1 As Range          ' rango (celda) donde se ingresó la fórmula

Function Funcion1(param1 As Variant, param2 As Variant, param3 As Variant)
    ' señalizar el redibujado del resultado de esta llamada
    disparar_F1 = True

    ' cálculo principal de la función (una simple suma de los parámetros)
    Funcion1 = param1 + param2 + param3

    ' definimos las distintas líneas resultantes de nuestra función
    resultado_F1(0) = "LA SUMA DE LOS PARÁMETROS"
    resultado_F1(1) = "GENERA EL SIGUIENTE RESULTADO:"
    resultado_F1(2) = CStr(param1) + " + " + CStr(param2) + " + " + CStr(param3) + " = " + CStr(Funcion1)

    ' guardamos referencia al rango de origen de la función (desde dónde se llamó)
    Set origen_F1 = Application.Caller
End Function
```

#### Código de Hoja1

Por otro lado [el evento Worksheet_Calculate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838823.aspx), ejecutado cada vez que se tiene que recalcular la hoja de trabajo, verifica que esté habilitada la bandera (definida en la otra función) y, si es así, *dibuja* el arreglo de resultados en las celdas debajo de donde se ingresó la fórmula.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    ' salir si no se calculó una llamada a Funcion1
    If Not disparar_F1 Then Exit Sub

    ' evitar redibujado posterior
    disparar_F1 = False

    ' imprimir el resultado de Funcion1
    ' NOTA: A2 corresponde a la celda inmediatamente debajo de la celda
    '       donde se ingresó la fórmula, A3 a la siguiente, etc.
    origen_F1.Range("A2").Value = resultado_F1(0)
    origen_F1.Range("A3").Value = resultado_F1(1)
    origen_F1.Range("A4").Value = resultado_F1(2)
End Sub
```

---

La siguiente imagen ilustra el resultado del código en Excel:

[image: ejemplo]

Los datos agregados (en las celdas `D3`, `D4` y `D5`) son valores independientes que pueden ser manipulados sin ningún problema; p.ej. cambiar el formato, copiar, modificar, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Creo que lo que buscas es esto:
Modifico un poco tu código. Sustituye el fragmento que he extraído por este modificado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde `NOMBREHOJA` es el nombre de la hoja donde quieres que se copien los resultados, y `NUMEROFILA` y `NUMEROCOLUMNA` son los de las casillas donde quieres que se escriba los resultados. Que una parte del texto salga en rojo en la imagen no significa nada

Comment: Prueba a poner el código en la respuesta, en lugar de poner una imagen del código